# VBA reading global from cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am a complete VBA newbie, so apologies in advance for the trivial question. Consider the following code:

```
Dim frog As Double

frog = Range("A1").Value


Function test_func(ByVal a As Double, ByVal b As Double)
    test_func = a ^ b
End Function


Private Sub btnAddNumbersFunction_Click()
    MsgBox test_func(frog, 3)
End Sub
```

When I try to compile this, I get an error of "invalid outside procedure" with the `"A1"` highlighted. (I am trying to define a model with some user-settable parameters, and so this would be useful to have).

Comment: You must assign a value to your variable inside your sub. Above the msgbox line.

Answer (score 1):

This code sample will compile, I have moved the variable assignment into the sub:

```
Dim frog As Double

Function test_func(ByVal a As Double, ByVal b As Double)
    test_func = a ^ b
End Function

Private Sub btnAddNumbersFunction_Click()
    'Assign values inside subs or functions
    frog = Range("A1").Value
    MsgBox test_func(frog, 3)
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that introducing another "initialization" sub, where the globals are initialized, does the trick. The suggestions in the other answers are not satisfactory for the reasons explained in the question: having to initialize (or even mention) the parameters in every procedure that implicitly uses them defeats the purpose. I am a bit mystified about why this is the design (this is unlike any other language I know), but MSFT moves in mysterious ways its wonders to perform.